# apache port disabled yet still working

Tags: apache, ssl

So I have inherited a linux server and am unclear about its apache configuration.

In the httpd.conf file it has this..

```
Listen 80
#Listen 443
```

Based on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html

```
"Note that if the <VirtualHost> is set for an address and port that
the server is not listening to, it cannot be accessed"
```

Yet this server uses SSL and is receiving requests successfully.

Here is one of the vhost directives..

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.somesite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/somesite
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.0.0.5:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/somesite
        ServerName www.somesite.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /sslcerts/mycert.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /sslcerts/mycert.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /sslcerts/mycert.gd_bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

The server is successfully receiving https requests to www.somesite.com

Is there some other configuration I am not seeing?
(also I'm not quite sure if using the internal IP 10.0.0.5 is correct)

Comment: Most likely https (so port 443) is enabled somewhere else, maybe an additional config file. `grep` is your friend here to easily look through those files. About the internal address: well it means that this particular virtual host will only be available on that address.

Comment: @arkascha yep, there was indeed another config file. thanks.

Comment: Probably in a folder called `conf.d` or similar. Invest a few minutes understanding how that works. The idea behind configuration files getting broken up massively has been introduced by openSUSE long ago and has caught on since. It allows additional packages, extensions and the like to just "drop in" their configuration options instead of having to riskily refactor a single existing large configuration file. So a more modular approach. Makes sense, works, just getting a bit used to :-)

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @arkascha a simple grep showed that there was an additional config file where port 443 was enabled